# Implementation of Redirection in User-Created Shell is not working properly

Tags: c, linux, bash, shell, pipe

I am trying to create a shell similar to bash, with redirection and pipes.

In my `main()`, I call a parser and then call the function below. The problem I am running into is the fact that when I run my shell, it outputs to the terminal correctly, but it does not output to the file correctly when using the `>`, `1>`, or `2>`.

For instance, if I call:

```
pwd > foo5.txt
```

I end up receiving:

```
> 
foo5.txt
```

In the text file I write too as opposed to the `stdout` (for ">"/"1>") or `stderr` (for "2>") which I am trying to achieve.

This is my code to fork and create the child process:

```
pid_t create_process(char *part, int const pipes[][2], int pipenum)
{
  pid_t pid;         // Initialize variables/pointers/arrays.
  char *args[64];
  int argc=0, n;
  char *arg=strtok(part, " \t");
  //char const **filename = args;


  while(arg != NULL)
    {
      args[argc++]=arg;
      arg=strtok(NULL, " \t");
    }

  args[argc++]=NULL;

  pid = fork();     // Create Fork.

  if(pid == 0)
  {
  int m;

  if(pipes[pipenum][STDIN_FILENO] >= 0)
    dup2(pipes[pipenum][STDIN_FILENO], STDIN_FILENO); // FD 0.

  if(pipes[pipenum][STDOUT_FILENO] >= 0)
    dup2(pipes[pipenum][STDOUT_FILENO], STDOUT_FILENO); // FD 1.

  // Close all pipes.
  for(m=0; m<64; m++)
    {
      if(pipes[m][STDIN_FILENO] >= 0)
        close(pipes[m][STDIN_FILENO]);
      if(pipes[m][STDOUT_FILENO] >= 0)
        close(pipes[m][STDOUT_FILENO]);
    }

  char *filename;
  char *newargs[64];
  newargs[63] = NULL;
  int i = 0;
  int j = 0;
  for(i = 0; i<64; i++)
  {
    if (args[i] == ">")
      {
        i++;
        if (args[i] != NULL)
          {
            filename = args[i];
            int redir = open(filename, O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IWUSR);
            dup2(redir, 1);
            close(redir);
          }
      }
    else if (args[i] == "2>")
      {
        i++;
        if (args[i] != NULL)
          {
            filename = args[i];
            int redir = open(filename, O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IWUSR);
            dup2(redir, 2);
            close(redir);
          }
      }

   else if (args[i] == "2>")
      {
        i++;
        if (args[i] != NULL)
          {
            filename = args[i];
            int redir = open(filename, O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IWGRP | S_IWUSR);
            dup2(redir, 2);
            close(redir);
          }
      }
    else if (args[i] == 0)
      {
        break;
      }
    else
      {
        newargs[j] = args[i];
        j++;
        cout<<"The arg is: " << newargs[j] <<endl;
      }
  }

    execvp(newargs[0], newargs);
    fprintf(stderr, "Command not found.\n");
    exit(255);

  }

else if(pid < 0)
{ // Error checking.
  fprintf(stderr, "Fork Failed\n");
}

return(pid);
}
```

UPDATE: Now my code will not recognize the commands, and the arguments being printed (for error checking) appear as such:

```
ls > foo5.txt 
The arg is: fprintf 
The arg is: 
The arg is: ▒ 
Command not found.
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a few problems here:

First, you have the for loop where you scan the command arguments for redirection syntax (if (strcmp(args[i],">")==0) and so on) - but if the condition is true (meaning you found a redirection character) you're always opening args[2], not args[i+1].

Second (and this is why the redirection syntax gets passed on to the command you're running as command arguments) - once you detect redirection syntax, you don't remove the redirection operator or the target filename from the list of arguments that you pass to execvp().

For instance, if args[] = {"echo", "a", ">", "logfile", 0}, your code detects a request to send the output to a new file called "logfile" and redirects the FDs correctly, but it still passes those three arguments ["a", ">", "logfile"] to the command.

Third - in your loop, you're calling execvp() at the end of each conditional statement - meaning that you don't get to the end of argument processing before you launch the new process. You need to process all the command arguments for shell syntax and **then** exec the command.

To fix the various problems with arg handling, probably the most effective solution is to build a new argument list as you're processing the raw ones provided by the user. For instance (using a==b as a string equality test for brevity)

```
if (args[i] == ">")
{
   i++; //skip the arg
   if (args[i]) {  // check we haven't hit the end of the arg list
      filename = args[i];
      // then open the file, dup it to stdout or whatever, etc...
}
else if (args[i] == "<") // repeat for other redirection syntax...
else {    // Finally, handle the case where we didn't identify any shell syntax:
   newargs[j] = args[i]; // Copy the arg to the new list, since it isn't "special"
   j++;  // Size of newargs[] has been increased
}
```

Note that this still doesn't handle things like no whitespace around the ">" character: "echo foo>file" will just print "foo>file"...  Syntax processing gets a little more complicated in that case, as you've got to account for quoting rules and escape characters to process the arguments correctly.

Comment: So I have followed your guidance (and your suggestions make a lot of sense) but I am still running into the issue where nothing is being written to the filename.

I have updated the main post with the revised code.

Comment: You've still got execvp() inside the for loop. That means on the first loop iteration, it will process the first one (or two) elements in args[], possibly adding something to newargs[] and possibly not - and then immediately call execvp(), preventing execution of the rest of the loop.  Also remember you need to format newargs[] the same way as args[] - be sure there's a null as the last element (and stop the for loop any time args[i]==0) then call execvp() after the loop.

Comment: I have updated the code again, but instead of getting more errors with the writing to files, now I'm just getting errors with calling the commands. I think it has to do with the 'break' I invoke when (args[i] == 0)... I'm not sure of a better way to escape the for loop but I'm having a strange error when I call the function now. To see that my newargs are being collected properly, I am receiving this: 

    ls > foo5.txt
    The arg is: fprintf
    The arg is: 
    The arg is: ▒   
    Command not found. 

I can post the rest of my code if need be because I have no idea of the cause.

Comment: Oh and the error code at the end of the comment is difficult to read, so I added it to the main post so it's easier to read.